# Why should I use parameters -std=c++14, -Wall, -Wextra, -Werror, -pedantic in C++

Tags: c++, parameters

I just started to learn C++ and I can not figure out what those parameters do. 
I guess -pedantic is used to control like a limit and -std=C++14 is telling us the specific C++ version.
Could someone help?

Comment: `-std=C++14 is telling us what kind of space we are using` Space? ◉_◉

Comment: Have you read your compiler's documentation for those flags?

Comment: If you are learning C++ now, you could also consider using `-std=c++17` to get the latest standard.  :-)

Comment: [Knock yourself out](https://linux.die.net/man/1/g++).

Answer (score 3):

The `-std=c++14` tells the compiler to use a specific version of the C++ standard. See e.g. [this Wikipedia article about C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14).

The other flags are about enabling more warnings by the compiler, so it might tell you if there's something wrong with the code. The `-Werror` flag tells the compiler to turn all warnings into errors.

Also note that all of these flags are specific to one or a few compilers, they are not "generic C++ options for all compilers".

Answer (score 1):

-std=c++14 will tell your compiler to use specifically 14 version of C++ standards.

To use latest one you can try -std=c++17.

-Wall is warn all. It turns on almost all the warnings, they're not errors but warnings.

-Wextra turns on some extra flags to display more warnings.

-pedantic will warn about some non-conformant parts of code.